# Donation on android app

Tags: android, paypal, google-play, donations

I know there is a lot of topics on this subject, but I would have recents informations about the donation process on android app'.

I've seen 2 librairies to integrate donation on app :

- [Paypal librairy for android app](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mobile/gs_MPL/)
- [Android-Donation-Lib for allow Google Play donation and Paypal at the same times](https://github.com/dschuermann/android-donations-lib/blob/master/README.md)

I have some questions about it :

1. Is it allow to only integrate the PayPal donation system on an android app put on the Google Play Store ?
2. If we put an app on Google Play Store and we integrate the Google Play donation, Google take 30% of the price ?
3. Are they some existing recent solution to integrate Donation system on android plateform ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The paypal library seems to include other capabilities outside of donations, while the github repo seems be just for donations.
2. The Google Play Store does not take any cut from your donations.
3. There are no official Google solutions to integrate donations onto Android, so you'll have to use the libraries you've already linked or figure out your own way. Alternatively, I think a lot of applications link to a donation web page that is hosted on the developer's website and the donations are all done via the webpage.